# Issue with comparing IP Addresses and Domain Names from from Certificate's SANs using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, openssl, cryptography

I'm working on a Python script which validate a certificate's Subject Alternative Names (SANs) against a predefined list of IP Addresses and subdomain. The certificate is generated using OpenSSL and I need to ensure that IP Address and domain names match the predefined pairs.

test.crt can be found below:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The certificate SANs have following format:

```
X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:test.testcluster.com, DNS:test01.testcluster.com, DNS:test02.testcluster.com, DNS:test03.testcluster.com, IP Address:192.168.1.140, IP Address:192.168.1.141, IP Address:192.168.1.142
    Signature Algorithm:
```

Commands to filter from test.crt

```
openssl x509 -in testcluster.crt -text -noout
openssl x509 -noout -text -in "test.crt" | grep -oP 'IP Address:\K[^,]*'
openssl x509 -noout -text -in "testcluster.crt" | grep -oP 'DNS:\K[^,]*' | sed -n '1!p'
```

I have tried several approaches, including using the 'cryptography' library, but I'm encountering challenges when comparing IP addresses and domain names. While domain name comparison is working, IP address comparison is giving me incorrect results.

As IP and domain names encoded in the script, this the actual IPs and names for cert, but when changing IP address in the script just for comparing with original cert (test.crt) its not working I mean instead of comparison giving output with validation successful  with new IP value.

Output:

case 1: when changing domain name for example: test03.testcluster01.com - Domain verification working

```
IP: xx.xx.xx.140", Domain: test01.testcluster.com, Certificate matches.
IP: xx.xx.xx.141", Domain: test02.testcluster.comt, Certificate matches.
Error: IP: xx.xx.xx.142", Domain: test03.testcluster01.com, Certificate does not match.
Certificate validation failed for one or more IP-domain pairs.
```

Case 2:  when changing IP Address for example: xx.xx.xx.150 - IP Address verification not working?

```
IP: xx.xx.xx.140", Domain: test01.testcluster.com, Certificate matches.
IP: xx.xx.xx.141", Domain: test02.testcluster.comt, Certificate matches.
IP: xx.xx.xx.150", Domain: test02.testcluster.comt, Certificate matches.
Certificate validation successful.
```

```py
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend



ip_dns_pairs = [
    ("xx.xx.xx.140", "test01.testcluster.com"),
    ("xx.xx.xx.141", "test02.testcluster.com"),
    ("xx.xx.xx.142", "test03.testcluster.com")
]


with open("test.crt", "rb") as cert_file:
    local_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_file.read(), default_backend())
    san_names = [name.value for name in local_cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(x509.SubjectAlternativeName).value]

all_match = True
for ip, dns in ip_dns_pairs:
    if any(((ip == name) or (dns == name)) for name in san_names):
        print(f"IP: {ip}, Domain: {dns}, Certificate matches.")

    else:
        print(f"Error: IP: {ip}, Domain: {dns}, Certificate does not match.")
        all_match = False

if all_match:
    print("Certificate validation successful.")
else:
    print("Certificate validation failed for one or more IP-domain pairs.")
```

tried different approach ipaddress module:

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import ipaddress


ip_dns_pairs = [
     (ipaddress.IPv4Address("xx.xx.xx.140"), "test01.testcluster.com"),
     (ipaddress.IPv4Address("xx.xx.xx.141"), "test02.testcluster.com"),
     (ipaddress.IPv4Address("xx.xx.xx.142"), "test03.testcluster.com")
]


with open("test.crt", "rb") as cert_file:
    local_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_file.read(), default_backend())
    san_names = [name.value for name in local_cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(x509.SubjectAlternativeName).value]

all_match = True
for ip, dns in ip_dns_pairs:
    if any(((ip == name) or (dns == name)) for name in san_names):
        print(f"IP: {ip}, Domain: {dns}, Certificate matches.")

    else:
        print(f"Error: IP: {ip}, Domain: {dns}, Certificate does not match.")
        all_match = False

if all_match:
    print("Certificate validation successful.")
else:
    print("Certificate validation failed for one or more IP-domain pairs.")
```

When changing IP address (142 to 155) and domain (testcluster to testcluster01 , nothing comparable just getting as output and validation successful :

```
IP: xx.xx.xx.140", Domain: test01.testcluster.com, Certificate matches.
IP: xx.xx.xx.141", Domain: test02.testcluster.com, Certificate matches.
IP: xx.xx.xx.150", Domain: test02.testcluster01.com, Certificate matches.
Certificate validation successful.
```

Could someone please provide guidance on how to accurately compare both IP addresses and domain names from the SANs against hardcoded pairs ?

Any insights or code/ shell script examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is not reproducible with the fix from the answer (see [online on replit](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/UprightHatefulBracket#main.py)). Post a non-productive test certificate with which the issue is reproducible.

Comment: @Topaco - Posted tested certificate

Comment: It also works with your test certificate, see [here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/LittleUtilizedVolcano#main.py). The Python code outputs the certificate, the DNS names and IPs, a test where all (DNS name, IP) pairs are correct, and a test where the third (DNS name, IP) pair is incorrect and the other two are correct. Both tests are verified correctly (first test: no error, second test: third pair does not match). Please describe in more detail what should not work.

Comment: @Topaco- thanks for checking and sharing, I mean only differing the IP  and domain name should be same. in your code line no: 76, something like this (ipaddress.IPv4Address("192.168.1.155"), "test03.testcluster.com"). So just validating IP address only. thanks a lot. domain validation was working as expected.

Comment: Your logic is implemented such that the success case is when for each (IP, DNSName) pair from ip_dns_pairs either the IP address or the DNS name or both are contained in san_names. Therefore, `(ipaddress.IPv4Address("192.168.1.150"), "test02.testcluster01.com")` produces a failure case (neither IP nor DNSName contained in the certificate), while `(ipaddress.IPv4Address("192.168.1.155"), "test03.testcluster.com")` is a success case (test03.testcluster.com contained in the certificate).

Comment: Maybe you want each (IP, DNSName) pair from ip_dns_pairs to have both the IP address and the DNSName in san_names, e.g. as here: https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/MistyUnrealisticFactor#main.py. In this case `(ipaddress.IPv4Address("192.168.1.155"), "test03.testcluster.com")` would be a failure case (because the IP is not contained in the certificate). Please note, whatever logic you need, you must describe it completely and unambiguously.

Comment: @Topaco- Yes I need this logic what you said in your last comment. thanks

Comment: The code linked in my last comment uses this logic and can be used as a blueprint.

Comment: @Topaco - Thank you! Yes I used and tested your last commented code, everything is working as expected but the only issue with when we have duplicate values, so its not validating in this case.

For example: in your last code line no: 102, if you set like this, i mean set same IP of test02.testcluster.com"  in test03, still validating certificate matches.
 (ipaddress.IPv4Address("192.168.1.141"), "test03.testcluster.com")

Comment: The right way is: Provide a *complete* specification of the logic, then perform the implementation based on that. I have already pointed this out to you. However, you provide an incomplete description that you constantly improve, so the code has to be adjusted. This approach is inefficient and a waste of time, you already have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

While a DNS name is returned as a `str`, an IP address is returned as an object of type `ipaddress.IPv4Adress`, and thus you're comparison of a `str` against `ipaddress.IPv4Adress` can never match. Instead, use this type in your ip_dns_pairs sequence:

```py
import ipaddress
.
.
.

ip_dns_pairs = [
    (ipaddress.IPv4Address("xx.xx.xx.140"), "test01.testcluster.com"),
    (ipaddress.IPv4Address("xx.xx.xx.141"), "test02.testcluster.com"),
    (ipaddress.IPv4Address("xx.xx.xx.142"), "test03.testcluster.com"),
]

.
.
.
```

I fairly certain the `ipaddress` module is a dependency for the `cryptography` module so it should be installed if you successfully installed `cryptography`.

Comment: Thanks @President James K. Polk
I tested as per your suggestion, but unfortunately its not working for both comparison of ip and doamin. 
ipaddress module is available.

Comment: You will need to edit your question to include a [mre].

Comment: updated all requirements, hope all in.